# The navbar stays next to the login page, how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css

Even if I set the navbar, it appears next to the login page. How can I fix? I want the navbar to be on top but it stays next to the login page even if I fix it with css.

My problem still persists. I Need Help )):

There is my CSS Code. But i didnt see any problem. Can u look?

I Was look everywhere but i didnt found.

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark text-white">
    <div class="container py-2">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebKent</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-webkent" aria-controls="navbar-webkent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-webkent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="kayit.html">Kayıt Ol</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="oturum.html">Oturum Aç</a>
          </li>    
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </nav>

    <div class="login">
      <form action="">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="email">E-Mail Adresiniz</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="email" name="" id="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="password">Şifre</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="" id="password">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="" id="check">
          <label class="form-control-label" for="check">Beni Hatırla</label>
        </div>
```

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.login{
    width: 360px;
    height: min-content;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.login h1{
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.login form {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.login form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.login form input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    background: url(./img/webkent.png);
    width: 170px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 200px;
    padding-bottom: -100px;
}
```

Comment: you are using boostrap and code seems fine and navbar should be on the top. If it is not, please add custom css that you have given. There will be some issue. Add css also in your question

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue since your HTML looks pretty normal to me.  Please include any relevant CSS in your question.

Comment: I can't add css, your code is giving an error warning and I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Your html above is missing closing tags....

Comment: And now its "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." saying...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I add my CSS Code.